# Linq type conversion on generic types

Tags: c#, linq, telerik-grid

I have this code I found but it doesnt work even after i tried many conversions. Basically it converts smartly a Datatable into a List that can be serializable.

The error is that it can't convert a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a `List<object>`:

```
public GridBindingData GetSomething() {

DataTable dt = GetDatatable();

var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>();

var data = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => columns.Select(c => new { Column = c.ColumnName, Value = r[c] })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Column, i => i.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null))
    .ToList<object>();

return new GridBindingData() { Data = data , Count = dt.Rows.Count };
}
```

I tried many conversions including:

```
List<object> newdata = (List<object>)data.AsEnumerable().Cast<object>();
```

Basicaly, the Data property of GridBindingData must have a `List<object>`. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a Telerik Grid. Hilariously, the [documentation for the GridBindingData.Data Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_gridbindingdata_data.html) doesn't mention it's type (sic), however the [constructor does indeed take a `List<object>`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/allmembers_t_telerik_web_ui_gridbindingdata.html)

Comment: yes it is for telerik grid, playing around the client side binding with webservice. To be honest, I wouldnt want to manually write every Datatable into a class or dynamic type. If this worked as the author who posted the snippet claims, it would be a perfect way to call it giving it a table.

Comment: I don't see a problem (see my updated answer). What is the _error_ you are getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mmm. It's not easy to see what error you are getting, but perhaps you need `.Cast<object>().ToList()`:

```
var data = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => columns.Select(c => new { Column = c.ColumnName, Value = r[c] })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Column, i => i.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null))
    .Cast<object>()
    .ToList();
```

**Edit** this should work flawlessly, tested in the REPL:

```
csharp> new Dictionary<string, string> { {"key","value"} }.ToList().Cast<object>();
{ [key, value] }

csharp> new Dictionary<string, string> { {"key","value"} }.Cast<object>().ToList();               
{ [key, value] }
```

Comment: After debugging it, I can confirm this works indeed. Before marking it as answered I need to understand why it still fails, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @LakiLai: Could it be because something in there is not serializable?

Comment: Well because we are converting to a list, it should be serializable. By using the JavaScriptSerializer I can see it works fine so this telerik component must not be reading it properly. Anyway, your code converted fine and problem now resides somewhere else. Thanks for your help and the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => columns.Select(c => new { Column = c.ColumnName, Value = r[c] })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Column, i => i.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null))
    .Select(x => (object)x)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want for your results: the dictionary keys, the values, both?

Assuming you want the values as objects, this should do it:

```
data = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => columns.Select(c => new { Column = c.ColumnName, Value = r[c] })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Column, i => i.Value != System.DBNull.Value ? i.Value : null))
    .Select(x => (object)x.Value)
    .ToList();
```