# Casting Anonymous type known model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, casting, controller, ienumerable

My model class is like this:

```
Public class abc {

         public string p1 get; set;
         public string p2 get; set;
}
```

and I am trying to cast like this

```
IEnumerable<abc> data= ( IEnumerable<abc>) (from d in d.GetAll()
                       select new {
                        p1= d.p1,
                        p2= d.p2
                     }).Distinct();
```

It is giving me error:

```
Unable to cast object of type <DistinctIterator>
```

Please advise

Comment: A quick search in stackoverflow has revealed this article which may be of help: [Linq type conversion on generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204930/linq-type-conversion-on-generic-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly cast an anonymous type to a known type. Do this instead:

```
IEnumerable<abc> data = from d in d.GetAll()
                    select new abc() {
                     p1 = d.p1,
                     p2 = d.p2
                  }).Distinct();
```

and if necessary create an IEqualityComparer to use with your Distinct call. See [Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049#Y0) for an example of implementing IEqualityComparer with Distinct.